# weird behaviour of insert when doing calling before getContent() call?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, attachment, dml

I am trying to generate multiple documents(which are VF page rendered as Word doc), by iterating over a map. As my first step, i am reading a report, generating a map(where key is a string and value is a List of DTO that i created) out of it and then save each key value pair as a record in a custom object.
Below is code for this :-

```
   ReadReportsData runReport = new ReadReportsData();
    grpBasedMap = runReport.readReportData();

    List<Test_Data__c> dataToInsertList = new List<Test_Data__c>();

    for(String str : grpBasedMap.keySet()){
       Test_Data__c cd = new Test_Data__c();
       cd.group_number__c = grpNbr;
       List<myDTO> dtoList = grpBasedMap.get(str);
       cd.Data_To_Populate_Json__c = JSON.serialize(dtoList);
       censusDataToInsertList.add(cd);

    }

     insert censusDataToInsertList;
     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

      for(String grpNbr : grpBasedMap.keySet()){
           mails.add(generateMail(grpNbr));            
        }
```

Once the records get inserted, i am triggering another method that generates the documents by calling getContent() method on the VF page reference. Code is as below :-

```
public Messaging.SingleEmailMessage generateMail(String grpNbr){

   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 


       // Reference the attachment page 
       PageReference wordDoc =  Page.DataAsAttachment;
       wordDoc.getParameters().put('grpNo',grpNbr);

       wordDoc.setRedirect(true);       

       // Take the Word content
       Blob b = wordDoc.getContent();

       // Create the email attachment
       Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
       efa.setFileName('Request.doc');
       efa.setBody(b);

       List<String> toAddresses = new List<String>{'naveen.rawat@test.com'};

       // Sets the paramaters of the email
       email.setSubject( 'Request' );
       email.setToAddresses(toAddresses );
       email.setHtmlBody(body);

       email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});

    return email;

}
```

In my VF page controller page when i query the inserted records an exception is thrown as below :-
    System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

Which is now I understand is because of the transaction scope, as on the single transaction I am inserting the record and getting the record, I referred this  [Fields missing using getContent call for Visualforce rendered as PDF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/fields-missing-using-getcontent-call-for-visualforce-rendered-as-pdf).

But how do i make sure that these request runs in separate transactions as i don't have any VF page component to define that.

I am thinking of handling the email logic in AFTER insert trigger of the Test_Data__c sObject. Thoughts and/or suggestions?

Comment: The link you reference includes a solution to the problem. Each request to the server is a separate transaction, and when the commandButton operation completes (and so has its transaction committed), its oncomplete attribute is used to make a second request to generate the PDF and that request can access the committed data. (Triggers won't help: they run in the same transaction.)

Comment: that's where i have problem is, that i don't have that kind of commandbutton where i can then do the onComplete action. i am just running my code via Execute Anonymous Window.

Comment: It will take 10 minutes to create a Visualforce page contain the command button and a controller to wrap your logic and then you can use the "known good" solution.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I was trying to resist creating a VF page and look for possibly other workarounds. Now I am gonna go ahead with your advice.

Comment: Sometimes a page is needed to run/test code. Another example is when making web service callouts. Here given that you can't commit a transaction in Apex code, using the browser to make two requests is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing my logic from a command button I am able to do the required functionality. I am now calling the method containing getContent() call on the onComplete() event of the Button as suggested in the following link.

[Fields missing using getContent call for Visualforce rendered as PDF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22654/fields-missing-using-getcontent-call-for-visualforce-rendered-as-pdf)